# how run document ready in external file js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function for select data in external file js

```
  function show_all() {
     work = "select";
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "server.php",
          data: "work="+work,
          success: function(data) {
              $("#boxtop").html(data);  
              $('#boxtop').animate({
              scrollTop: $('#boxtop').get(0).scrollHeight}, 0);
          } 
      });  
  }
```

and document ready work in html index but dont work in external file js

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   show_all();
});
```

Comment: The script <script type="text/javascript" src="yourscript.js"></script> must be after of you jquery file script? Is it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you need to add this line to your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourscript.js"></script>
```

in a head section, where in src you should put a path to your external file

Comment: This not my problem i added this line before .. my problem is whay document ready not work in external

Comment: Then there are not enough details in your question. It might be invalid path to your file, some issues with jQuery, etc. Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Try to read answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined
But it seems to me that It is a problem with jQuery. Check if it is included to your page and that it is included before your external file.